# code for fitting a curve to the output which is a function of inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I have a CSV file with
four inputs: dp, rho, d, t.
one output: PD.

Since the output PD depends on the four inputs, I want to fit a an equation for PD that depends on the input. The function that I want to fit is given as follows.
PD= H * (dp **A) * (rho ** B) * (d ** C) * ((D * t ** 3) + (E * t ** 2) + (F * t) + G).
Here we have 8 coefficients A B C D E F G H.

I have written the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Define the function equation
def equation(dp, rho, d, t, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H):
    return H * (dp ** A) * (rho ** B) * (d ** C) * ((D * t ** 3) + (E * t ** 2) + (F * t) + G)

# Load the data from the CSV file
data = np.loadtxt('/content/PIML.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)  # Assuming the first row    contains column headers

# Extract the input variables (dp, rho, d, t) and the output variable (PD)
dp = data[:, 0]
rho = data[:, 1]
d = data[:, 2]
t = data[:, 3]
PD = data[:, 4]

# Perform the regression
initial_guess = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]  # Initial guess for the coefficients A, B,  C, D, E, F, G, H
coefficients, _ = curve_fit(equation, (dp, rho, d, t), PD, p0=initial_guess)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-53b876919899> in <cell line: 20>()
     18 # Perform the regression
     19 initial_guess = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]  # Initial guess for the coefficients A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
---> 20 coefficients, _ = curve_fit(equation, (dp, rho, d, t), PD, p0=initial_guess)
     21 
     22 # Extract the optimized coefficients

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py in func_wrapped(params)
    499     if transform is None:
    500         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 501             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    502     elif transform.ndim == 1:
    503         def func_wrapped(params):

TypeError: equation() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'E', 'F', 'G', and 'H'
```

Sample Data:

```
dp,rho,d,t,PD
299,741,0.11,0,0
299,741,0.11,0.014484,0.0792
299,741,0.11,0.02897,0.2124
299,741,0.11,0.043455,0.35664
299,741,0.11,0.057941,0.65911
299,741,0.11,0.072426,0.96536
299,741,0.11,0.086911,1.3395
299,741,0.11,0.1014,1.7787
299,741,0.11,0.11588,2.2718
299,741,0.11,0.13037,2.9307
299,741,0.11,0.14485,3.7194
299,741,0.11,0.15934,4.6158
299,741,0.11,0.17382,5.6313
299,741,0.11,0.18831,6.7398
299,741,0.11,0.20279,8.1185
299,741,0.11,0.21728,9.5152
299,741,0.11,0.23176,11.053
299,741,0.11,0.24625,12.734
299,741,0.11,0.26073,14.52
299,741,0.11,0.27522,16.536
299,741,0.11,0.2897,18.602
299,741,0.11,0.30419,20.73
299,741,0.11,0.31868,22.758
299,741,0.11,0.33316,24.748
299,741,0.11,0.34765,26.642
299,741,0.11,0.36213,28.335
299,741,0.11,0.37662,29.801
299,741,0.11,0.3911,31.15
299,741,0.11,0.40559,32.557
299,741,0.11,0.42007,33.796
299,741,0.11,0.43456,35.007
299,741,0.11,0.44904,36.123
299,741,0.11,0.46353,37.032
299,741,0.11,0.47801,37.736
299,741,0.11,0.4925,38.184
299,741,0.11,0.50698,38.535
295,741,0.11,0,0
295,741,0.11,0.014486,0.039764
295,741,0.11,0.028971,0.40011
295,741,0.11,0.043456,0.78876
295,741,0.11,0.057941,1.3216
295,741,0.11,0.072427,2.0524
295,741,0.11,0.086912,3.0065
295,741,0.11,0.1014,4.0218
295,741,0.11,0.11588,5.2133
295,741,0.11,0.13037,6.6099
295,741,0.11,0.14485,8.0899
295,741,0.11,0.15934,9.71
295,741,0.11,0.17382,11.384
295,741,0.11,0.18831,13.069
295,741,0.11,0.20279,14.75
295,741,0.11,0.21728,16.447
295,741,0.11,0.23176,18.189
295,741,0.11,0.24625,19.974
295,741,0.11,0.26073,21.677
295,741,0.11,0.27522,23.456
295,741,0.11,0.28971,25.188
295,741,0.11,0.30419,26.715
295,741,0.11,0.31868,28.245
295,741,0.11,0.33316,29.726
295,741,0.11,0.34765,31.1
295,741,0.11,0.36213,32.345
295,741,0.11,0.37662,33.504
295,741,0.11,0.3911,34.331
295,741,0.11,0.40559,34.88
295,741,0.11,0.42007,35.647
295,741,0.11,0.43456,36.362
295,741,0.11,0.44904,36.647
295,741,0.11,0.46353,36.921
295,741,0.11,0.47801,37.34
295,741,0.11,0.4925,37.747
295,741,0.11,0.50698,38.036
290,741,0.11,0,0
290,741,0.11,0.014485,0.072
290,741,0.11,0.028971,0.34949
290,741,0.11,0.043456,0.98103
290,741,0.11,0.057941,1.7397
290,741,0.11,0.072427,2.6865
290,741,0.11,0.086912,4.0293
290,741,0.11,0.1014,5.6093
290,741,0.11,0.11588,7.2436
290,741,0.11,0.13037,8.9937
290,741,0.11,0.14485,10.967
290,741,0.11,0.15934,12.957
290,741,0.11,0.17382,14.696
290,741,0.11,0.18831,16.298
290,741,0.11,0.20279,17.771
290,741,0.11,0.21728,19.259
290,741,0.11,0.23176,20.671
290,741,0.11,0.24625,21.919
290,741,0.11,0.26073,22.723
290,741,0.11,0.27522,23.663
290,741,0.11,0.28971,24.544
290,741,0.11,0.30419,25.39
290,741,0.11,0.31868,26.192
290,741,0.11,0.33316,26.736
290,741,0.11,0.34765,27.399
290,741,0.11,0.36213,28.07
290,741,0.11,0.37662,28.742
290,741,0.11,0.3911,29.43
290,741,0.11,0.40559,29.973
290,741,0.11,0.42007,30.506
290,741,0.11,0.43456,30.84
290,741,0.11,0.44904,31.412
290,741,0.11,0.46353,31.874
290,741,0.11,0.47801,32.508
290,741,0.11,0.4925,33.016
290,741,0.11,0.50698,33.477
280,741,0.11,0,0
280,741,0.11,0.014485,0.2628
280,741,0.11,0.028971,0.6697
280,741,0.11,0.043456,1.1681
280,741,0.11,0.057941,1.9244
280,741,0.11,0.072427,3.1121
280,741,0.11,0.086912,4.5726
280,741,0.11,0.1014,6.2323
280,741,0.11,0.11588,7.9133
280,741,0.11,0.13037,9.5372
280,741,0.11,0.14485,11.092
280,741,0.11,0.15934,12.367
280,741,0.11,0.17382,13.405
280,741,0.11,0.18831,14.334
280,741,0.11,0.20279,15.183
280,741,0.11,0.21728,15.896
280,741,0.11,0.23176,16.539
280,741,0.11,0.24625,17.195
280,741,0.11,0.26073,17.776
280,741,0.11,0.27522,18.361
280,741,0.11,0.28971,18.954
280,741,0.11,0.30419,19.528
280,741,0.11,0.31868,20.018
280,741,0.11,0.33316,20.632
280,741,0.11,0.34765,21.102
280,741,0.11,0.36213,21.601
280,741,0.11,0.37662,22.084
280,741,0.11,0.3911,22.498
280,741,0.11,0.40559,23.025
280,741,0.11,0.42007,23.528
280,741,0.11,0.43456,23.99
280,741,0.11,0.44904,24.435
280,741,0.11,0.46353,24.877
280,741,0.11,0.47801,25.18
280,741,0.11,0.4925,25.512
280,741,0.11,0.50698,25.925
599,741,0.11,0,0
599,741,0.11,0.014486,0.0648
599,741,0.11,0.028971,1.6352
599,741,0.11,0.043456,3.3634
599,741,0.11,0.057942,5.7895
599,741,0.11,0.072427,8.8894
599,741,0.11,0.086912,12.485
599,741,0.11,0.1014,16.687
599,741,0.11,0.11588,20.877
599,741,0.11,0.13037,24.873
599,741,0.11,0.14485,28.732
599,741,0.11,0.15934,32.416
599,741,0.11,0.17382,35.696
599,741,0.11,0.18831,38.581
599,741,0.11,0.20279,39.819
599,741,0.11,0.21728,40.077
599,741,0.11,0.23176,40.077
599,741,0.11,0.24625,40.083
599,741,0.11,0.26073,40.085
599,741,0.11,0.27522,40.09
599,741,0.11,0.28971,40.092
599,741,0.11,0.30419,40.091
599,741,0.11,0.31868,40.096
599,741,0.11,0.33316,40.1
599,741,0.11,0.34765,40.092
599,741,0.11,0.36213,40.097
599,741,0.11,0.37662,40.098
599,741,0.11,0.3911,40.102
599,741,0.11,0.40559,40.108
599,741,0.11,0.42007,40.106
599,741,0.11,0.43456,40.112
599,741,0.11,0.44904,40.11
599,741,0.11,0.46353,40.106
599,741,0.11,0.47801,40.103
599,741,0.11,0.4925,40.106
599,741,0.11,0.50698,40.112
595,741,0.11,0,0
595,741,0.11,0.014486,0.34596
595,741,0.11,0.028971,2.1074
595,741,0.11,0.043456,4.0943
595,741,0.11,0.057942,6.7186
595,741,0.11,0.072427,10.048
595,741,0.11,0.086912,13.925
595,741,0.11,0.1014,17.558
595,741,0.11,0.11588,20.734
595,741,0.11,0.13037,23.337
595,741,0.11,0.14485,25.693
595,741,0.11,0.15934,27.613
595,741,0.11,0.17382,29.206
595,741,0.11,0.18831,30.698
595,741,0.11,0.20279,32.027
595,741,0.11,0.21728,33.347
595,741,0.11,0.23176,34.393
595,741,0.11,0.24625,35.578
595,741,0.11,0.26073,36.646
595,741,0.11,0.27522,37.619
595,741,0.11,0.28971,38.457
595,741,0.11,0.30419,39.037
595,741,0.11,0.31868,39.285
595,741,0.11,0.33316,39.631
595,741,0.11,0.34765,39.888
595,741,0.11,0.36213,39.984
595,741,0.11,0.37662,40.173
595,741,0.11,0.3911,40.27
595,741,0.11,0.40559,40.341
595,741,0.11,0.42007,40.26
595,741,0.11,0.43456,40.245
595,741,0.11,0.44904,40.21
595,741,0.11,0.46353,40.315
595,741,0.11,0.47801,40.25
595,741,0.11,0.4925,40.172
595,741,0.11,0.50698,40.228
590,741,0.11,0,0
590,741,0.11,0.014485,0.86136
590,741,0.11,0.02897,2.4175
590,741,0.11,0.043456,4.6342
590,741,0.11,0.057941,7.539
590,741,0.11,0.072426,10.837
590,741,0.11,0.086911,14.06
590,741,0.11,0.1014,16.724
590,741,0.11,0.11588,18.562
590,741,0.11,0.13037,19.853
590,741,0.11,0.14485,20.977
590,741,0.11,0.15934,22.071
590,741,0.11,0.17382,23.115
590,741,0.11,0.18831,24.101
590,741,0.11,0.20279,25.014
590,741,0.11,0.21728,25.921
590,741,0.11,0.23176,26.879
590,741,0.11,0.24625,27.788
590,741,0.11,0.26073,28.657
590,741,0.11,0.27522,29.494
590,741,0.11,0.28971,30.339
590,741,0.11,0.30419,31.133
590,741,0.11,0.31868,31.912
590,741,0.11,0.33316,32.656
590,741,0.11,0.34765,33.369
590,741,0.11,0.36213,34.059
590,741,0.11,0.37662,34.671
590,741,0.11,0.3911,35.346
590,741,0.11,0.40559,36.009
590,741,0.11,0.42007,36.619
590,741,0.11,0.43456,37.23
590,741,0.11,0.44904,37.702
590,741,0.11,0.46353,38.135
590,741,0.11,0.47801,38.498
590,741,0.11,0.4925,38.782
590,741,0.11,0.50698,39.02
580,741,0.11,0,0
580,741,0.11,0.014485,0.65667
580,741,0.11,0.02897,2.2091
580,741,0.11,0.043456,4.3362
580,741,0.11,0.057941,7.1723
580,741,0.11,0.072426,10.049
580,741,0.11,0.086911,12.48
580,741,0.11,0.1014,14.145
580,741,0.11,0.11588,15.11
580,741,0.11,0.13037,15.827
580,741,0.11,0.14485,16.57
580,741,0.11,0.15934,17.328
580,741,0.11,0.17382,18.057
580,741,0.11,0.18831,18.871
580,741,0.11,0.20279,19.683
580,741,0.11,0.21728,20.476
580,741,0.11,0.23176,21.243
580,741,0.11,0.24625,21.931
580,741,0.11,0.26073,22.59
580,741,0.11,0.27522,23.264
580,741,0.11,0.28971,23.927
580,741,0.11,0.30419,24.614
580,741,0.11,0.31868,25.251
580,741,0.11,0.33316,25.866
580,741,0.11,0.34765,26.466
580,741,0.11,0.36213,27.021
580,741,0.11,0.37662,27.571
580,741,0.11,0.3911,28.139
580,741,0.11,0.40559,28.682
580,741,0.11,0.42007,29.246
580,741,0.11,0.43456,29.761
580,741,0.11,0.44904,30.254
580,741,0.11,0.46353,30.823
580,741,0.11,0.47801,31.352
580,741,0.11,0.4925,31.853
580,741,0.11,0.50698,32.25
899,741,0.11,0,0
899,741,0.11,0.014486,0.28897
899,741,0.11,0.028971,2.3951
899,741,0.11,0.043456,5.196
899,741,0.11,0.057942,9.5081
899,741,0.11,0.072427,15.023
899,741,0.11,0.086912,20.636
899,741,0.11,0.1014,25.949
899,741,0.11,0.11588,30.432
899,741,0.11,0.13037,34.504
899,741,0.11,0.14485,37.687
899,741,0.11,0.15934,39.307
899,741,0.11,0.17382,39.782
899,741,0.11,0.18831,40.005
899,741,0.11,0.20279,39.974
899,741,0.11,0.21728,39.96
899,741,0.11,0.23176,40.01
899,741,0.11,0.24625,40.029
899,741,0.11,0.26073,40.147
899,741,0.11,0.27522,40.182
899,741,0.11,0.28971,40.236
899,741,0.11,0.30419,40.175
899,741,0.11,0.31868,40.204
899,741,0.11,0.33316,40.128
899,741,0.11,0.34765,40.165
899,741,0.11,0.36213,40.283
899,741,0.11,0.37662,40.197
899,741,0.11,0.3911,40.168
899,741,0.11,0.40559,40.228
899,741,0.11,0.42007,40.185
899,741,0.11,0.43456,40.181
899,741,0.11,0.44904,40.103
899,741,0.11,0.46353,40.181
899,741,0.11,0.47801,40.301
899,741,0.11,0.4925,40.136
899,741,0.11,0.50698,40.179
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, your sample data doesn't have the arguments E,F, G, or H. You can remove those from the *equation* function like

```
def equation(dp, rho, d, t, A, B, C, D):
        return H * (dp ** A) * (rho ** B) * (d ** C) * ((D * t ** 3)
```

and then modify your *curve_fit* call

```
coefficients, _ = curve_fit(equation, (dp, rho, d, t), PD)
```

Note that the initial values is set to 1 by default. So, you don't have to set it specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this fixes the issue:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Define the function equation
# def equation(dp, rho, d, t, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H):
def equation(ind, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H):
    return H * (ind[0] ** A) * (ind[1] ** B) * (ind[2] ** C) * ((D * ind[3] ** 3) + (E * ind[3] ** 2) + (F * ind[3]) + G)

# Load the data from the CSV file
data = np.loadtxt('\content\PIML.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)  # Assuming the first row    contains column headers

# Extract the input variables (dp, rho, d, t) and the output variable (PD)
dp = data[:, 0]
rho = data[:, 1]
d = data[:, 2]
t = data[:, 3]
PD = data[:, 4]

# Perform the regression
initial_guess = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]  # Initial guess for the coefficients A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
coefficients, _ = curve_fit(equation, (dp, rho, d, t), PD, p0=initial_guess)

# Extract the optimized coefficients
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H = coefficients

# Print the optimized coefficients
print("Optimized Coefficients:")
print("A:", A)
print("B:", B)
print("C:", C)
print("D:", D)
print("E:", E)
print("F:", F)
print("G:", G)
print("H:", H)
```

I created `ind` as a tuple argument for `equation()` because the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) says that `xdata`must fit as first argument of the function argument of `curve_fit`. Also, your original guess array has 7 elements, not 8 from `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H` in your `equation()` function so I added a `1.0` in the end of `intial_guess`. The output is:

```
Optimized Coefficients:
A: 0.9997872748265457
B: 25.067761879355505
C: 295.8682855207864
D: -247.07433221196385
E: -247.0916104993987
F: -247.07677473418636
G: -247.0817293585099
H: 739.8985912595286
```